# Web design html/css - Looking to build a page with non-aligned images

Tags: html, css

Hi I am learning webdesign at the moment and I would like to know what would be the best way for displaying multiple images of different size in a non-aligned layout.

I wanted to post an image to give an idea about what im trying to do but I cant =(

I use html/css on dreamweaver cs6

Any help is appreciated, thank you

*Edited
A picture linked on that post where I asked the same question, there you will see an exemple of what Im trying to do: http://www.designerstalk.com/forums/web-design/73418-web-design-html-css-looking-build-page-non-aligned-images.html

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I would like to make a webpage with a gallery of different images of different size but that are not alligned one after the other. The goal is to do something artistic. I understand how to use the div but as I said I am new to webdesign.

Comment: Why the two downvote I dont understand.

Comment: When you ask a question like that you have to try to make quite clear what you want to do. That is why there is a function at stackoverflow to post code for instance. I guess that is why you are downvoted because your question is quite unclear and you dont provide any code.

Comment: The question was ambiguous and could be explained better. However, if he had been allowed to link an image without the need for 10 rep, at least we would know what he was trying to achieve.

Comment: You need to make an effort and post some code. Most clients want responsive design these days and doing that particular layout in a way that will respond to resize can be done with Masonry http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KDkBI http://masonry.desandro.com/ you will need to read the docs and adjust margins, widths, and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Have a play with this. I have achieved this with absolute positioning. Learn more here:

http://learnlayout.com/position.html

http://www.impressivewebs.com/absolute-position-css/

Plenty more lessons to be found!

**Updated fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/gf69S/4/

HTML

```
<div class="gallery">
<img src="http://ima.gs/50x100.png" />
<img src="http://ima.gs/50x100.png" style="bottom: 0;" />
<img src="http://ima.gs/50x20.png" style="left: 50px;" />
<img src="http://ima.gs/50x100.png" style="left: 50px; top: 20px;" />
<img src="http://ima.gs/75x80.png" style="left: 50px; top: 120px;" />
<img src="http://ima.gs/75x80.png" style="left: 100px;" />
<img src="http://ima.gs/75x40.png" style="top: 80px; left: 100px;" />
<img src="http://ima.gs/50x80.png" style="top: 120px; left: 125px;" />   
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery { position: relative; height: 200px; }
.gallery img { position: absolute; }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot man for your replay. But it would help so much if I could show you a picture as an example of what i would like to do but I cant post an image here (doesnt have 10rep yet). *** Here I posted my question with an image linked, please check it out you will quickly understand. thank you again. http://www.designerstalk.com/forums/web-design/73418-web-design-html-css-looking-build-page-non-aligned-images.html

Comment: I have edited my answer. Take that as an example and make it work for you :)